# how can recursion return

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

wrong Version：

```
def mergeSort(s):
    if(len(s)<=1):
        return s
    else:
        mid=len(s)/2
        front=s[:mid]
        back=s[mid:]
        mergeSort(front)       
        mergeSort(back)
        return merge(front,back)
```

right Version:

```
def mergeSort(s):
    if(len(s)<=1):
        return s
    else:
        mid=len(s)/2
        front=mergeSort(s[:mid])
        back=mergeSort(s[mid:])        
        return merge(front,back)
```

why return origin array in wrong version?what's the difference between two version in recursion process?
the same confusion in quick sort,please help me improve code,thanks.and explain me what should i do with recursion return if I want return data after process not return origin data.

```
def QuickSort(seq):
    if(len(seq)<=0):        
        return seq
    else:
        j=partion(seq)
        left=QuickSort(seq[:j])        
        right=QuickSort(seq[j+1:])
```

Comment: Answers been posted, but you should look up how to write this there's a cleaner way than this.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
If nothing else, insert a couple of strategic `print` statements to trace the data and control flow.  Don't just stare at the code: make it report what it's doing at each point.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning the original data, it's been recursively modified and when you just "look at the method", you only see the first and last iteration of that process.

Your first version is wrong because you never "capture" then returned merged array

Recursion returns no differently than other functions

Comment: thank you,what should I change in QuickSort if I don't want to change partion function?

Comment: I'd say your initial question was simply about recursion and merge sort, please limit your posts into singular problems and ask specifically about QuickSort in a separate function. Also, since I can't see your partition function, I can't even say what is wrong with that code

Comment: Thank you , It's the first time I ask question in stackoverflow, I didn't discribe clearly and I don't know how can I thank you for answer me .

Comment: You are welcome to  edit your questions to rephrase what you want